# Find Minimum Possible difference between numbers with unknown digits

Tags: php, regex, numbers, difference

I have some cases as follows.

- 1? 2?
- ?2? ??3
- ? ?
- ?5 ?0

Now what I am supposed to do is to find some values in place of question marks, that would give produce the minimum possible difference between the 2 numbers.

Answers Should be like

- 19 20
- 023 023
- 0 0
- 05 00

Note : the number which will be produced after the minimum absolute difference between the 2 values must be smallest. As in, the last case could be 15 and 10 with the absolute difference to be 5 but it is invalid.

I tried some permutation combination ideas for replacing the question marks for both numbers individually and then find out the number but the length of the number could go up to 18 digits per number. Hence I believe it wouldn't be a good idea.

Then I tried to search for similar questions but that didn't help.
I still think that `regex` could be helpful to solve this question but am stuck with how to do it.

Any help is welcome!! Thanx!

The language shall be Php.. I am working with Php.

Comment: Regex might be useful for retrieving the pieces into variables, but it certainly can't be used to do math (finding a min, max, difference, etc). You can the pairs into a 2 capturing groups by using `([\d\?]+) ([\d\?]+)`, assuming there is always 1 space between them.

Comment: what should happen if you have : 2? ??3

Comment: both the numbers would always have the same length. @Fky

Comment: @TirthrajBarot and always by pair ? or it can be like 2? ??3 ??4 ??3

Comment: As in, the last case could be 15 and 10 with the absolute difference to be 5 but it is invalid. Why is it invalid ? 15-10 is also 5. isn't it ?

Comment: that is because the numbers should be the smallest possible numbers to produce the smallest absolute difference. @Fky

Comment: and yes.. It will always be a pair of 2 numbers.

Comment: as it can go upto 18 digits per number, that's beyond a simple problem, rather seems like a problem of a contest problem set.... you should put a bounty on it ...

Comment: @Addison, regexes [can be used to do math](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47566/adding-numbers-with-regex), though it's obviously an ill-advised approach for real-world applications.

Comment: @dan1111 I get you, but please spare me from code golfs of this atrocity.

Comment: @Addison i went for lunch, and came back with the algo, and came back to see you already did it ! but my algo is different, won't share ;)

Comment: @Maverick_Mrt Dang, I'm curious now. I'll have my dinner and see if I can come up with what your solution might have been

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I got a solution.

#### Explanation:

Uses regex to grab the two numbers, then compares them in pairs from left to right, starting with the assumption they're equal. Meaning they both resolve to the same number wherever possible, or 0 if they are both `?`.

After there is a pair of numbers that aren't equal, it starts setting the lower ones `?`'s to `9`, and the higher ones `?`'s to `0`, to make them as close as possible.

[Here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3d444a43517d943fdd69f28a45d7f44b8880a3fe) is an example of it in action.

```
function minDiff($str) {
    preg_match("/([\d\?]+) ([\d\?]+)/", $str, $matches);
    
    $first = $matches[1];
    $second = $matches[2];
    
    $biggest = 0; // -1 = first, 0 = none, 1 = second
    
    $firstResult = 0;
    $secondResult = 0;
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($first); $i++) {
        $powerValue = strlen($first) - $i - 1;
        if ($biggest != 0) { // not equal
            if (!strcmp($first[$i], '?') && !strcmp($second[$i], '?')) {
                if ($biggest > 0) { // second is biggest
                    $firstResult += 9 * pow(10, $powerValue);
                } else { // first is biggest
                    $secondResult += 9 * pow(10, $powerValue);
                }
            } elseif (!strcmp($first[$i], '?')) {
                if ($biggest > 0) { // second is biggest
                    $firstResult += 9 * pow(10, $powerValue);
                }
                $secondResult += $second[$i] * pow(10, $powerValue);
            } elseif (!strcmp($second[$i], '?')) {
                if ($biggest < 0) { // first is biggest
                    $secondResult += 9 * pow(10, $powerValue);
                }
                $firstResult += $first[$i] * pow(10, $powerValue);
            } else {
                $firstResult += $first[$i] * pow(10, $powerValue);
                $secondResult += $second[$i] * pow(10, $powerValue);
            }
        } else { // both equal (so far)
            if (!strcmp($first[$i], '?')) {
                $firstResult += $second[$i] * pow(10, $powerValue);
                $secondResult += $second[$i] * pow(10, $powerValue);
            } elseif (!strcmp($second[$i], '?')) {
                $firstResult += $first[$i] * pow(10, $powerValue);
                $secondResult += $first[$i] * pow(10, $powerValue);
            } else {
                if (intval($first[$i]) > intval($second[$i])) {
                    $biggest = -1;
                } elseif (intval($first[$i]) < intval($second[$i])) {
                    $biggest = 1;
                }
                $firstResult += $first[$i] * pow(10, $powerValue);
                $secondResult += $second[$i] * pow(10, $powerValue);
            }
            
            // Find if next number will change
            if (($i + 1) < strlen($first) && strcmp($first[$i + 1], '?') && strcmp($second[$i + 1], '?')) {
                $diff = preg_replace('/\?/', '0', substr($first, $i + 1)) - preg_replace('/\?/', '0', substr($second, $i + 1));
                echo "$diff\n";
                // Check to see if you need to add 1 to the value for this loop
                if ($diff > pow(10, $powerValue) / 2) {
                    $secondResult += pow(10, $powerValue);
                    $biggest = 1;
                } elseif ($diff < pow(10, $powerValue) / -2) {
                    $firstResult += pow(10, $powerValue);
                    $biggest = -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    echo "first: ".str_pad($firstResult, strlen($first), "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)."\n";
    echo "second: ".str_pad($secondResult, strlen($second), "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)."\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Awesome job man!! Thanx a lot.. Just one more question.. Is there any way you can preserve the leading zeros? as in for the case of ?2? ??3 I am getting 23 23 which is correct but i need 023 023.

Comment: Sure, I'll work that in with version 2.0. Coming right up

Comment: Won't this output `09` and `01` for `?1` and `?9`? Shouldn't that be `09` and `11`?

Comment: @SebastianProske I have added an answer that will cover your input too

Comment: Sadly OP provided only a few very simple test cases, so here are some futher test cases (hope I got them all right): `?4001? - ?9??9?` => `140010 - 099999`, `1?????9 - 1?????1` => `1000009 - 1000011`, `12?4?6? - 2?3?5?7` => `1294969 - 2030507`, `?4? - ?9?` => `049 - 090`, `?4? - ?94` => `049 - 094`, `?4? - ?95` => `140 - 095`, `?40? - ?9?1` => `1400 - 0991`. As OP already accepted your answer, I'm fine if you ignore this, however I don't think your answer is correct at the current state.

Comment: I came here from my strong suit (regex), but that's no excuse! I'll be damned if I don't fix such naïve code. Thanks for going to the effort of proving me wrong @SebastianProske

Comment: Go ahead and try now @SebastianProske. I think even you'll be satisfied [=)](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eb101572b8fadc204ed810811e38700b611fcbfd)

Comment: I think `$five` is still not correct, should be 049 and 094 (diff 45) and not 140 and 094 (diff 46)